# How to sign out of a specific session for a Microsoft Account?

Tags: entra-id

If I am logged into a Microsoft Account (e.g. Office 365) in many places, and I want to end an active login session that is specific, but not end ALL active login sessions, how do I actually do that?

I can only find documentation on how to log out of all active sessions but not a specific one.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can't find the way in the documentation because it does not exist. The only option offered is to sign out everywhere